# Expected Values of the product of a random variable and an indicator random variable

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable $\in$ $L_{1}$

Given that $E[X]$ = $1$ , does that necessarily mean that : 
$E[X*1_{A}]$ = $P[A]$ ?

My intuition is yes, since this is can be decomposed to $E[X]$ * $P[A]$ = $1$ * $P[A]$.

Am i correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without further assumptions, I guess (your last equation holds in general only if $X$ and $\mathbf{1}_A$ are independent). Take $X$ the random variable equal to $0$ with probability $9/10$, and $10$ with probability $1/10$; and $A=\{X=0\}$. Then $$\mathbb{E}[X] = 1$$ but $$\mathbb{E}[X\mathbf{1}_A] = 0$$
while $\mathbb{P}(A) = 9/10$.

Answer (score 3):

In general $\mathbb{E}[X \cdot Y] = \mathbb{E}[X] \cdot \mathbb{E}[Y]$, which you are trying to do, applies only if $X,Y$ are independent.